# Serlvet mixing session responses

Tags: java, servlets

I'm developing an Android printing application. A part of my application is a local server that receive files from the users. 
I implemented the server in Tomcat Java servlet.
My problem is that when two devices sending 2 files instantaneously to the server, there is two possible results:
1. One client receives a good response, and the second client receives an empty response.
2. One client receives a response of the second client and vise versa.

Here is my servlet code:

```
    protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                try {
                    writer = response.getWriter();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    // get access to file that is uploaded from client
                    Part p1 = request.getPart("File");
                    InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();

                    // read filename which is sent as a part
                    Part p2  = request.getPart("MetaData");
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(p2.getInputStream());
                    String stringJson = s.nextLine();    // read filename from stream
                    s.close();

                    json = new JSONObject(stringJson);
                    fileName = new String(json.getString("FileName").getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    fileDirectory = BASE + request.getSession().getId();
                    File dir = new File(fileDirectory);
                    dir.mkdir();
                    // get filename to use on the server
                    String outputfile = BASE + dir.getName() + "/" + fileName;  // get path on the server
                    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream (outputfile);

                    // write bytes taken from uploaded file to target file
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int ch = is.read(buffer);
                    while (ch != -1) { 
                        os.write(buffer);
                        ch = is.read(buffer);
                    }
                    os.close();
                    is.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    writer.println("Exception -->" + ex.getMessage());
                }
                finally { 
                    try {
                        myRequest = request;
                        try {
                            printFile(request.getSession().getId());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            writer.println("Exception -->" + e.getMessage());
                        }
                        writer.close();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        writer.println("Exception -->" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }               
            }
        }.run();

    }
```

The tomcat server is running over Ubuntu 13.04 as a virtual machine.
Any idea?

Comment: Don't do threads in servlest unless you really know what you are doing. (yes, I see you removed the thread invocation in the posted example, but why else would you bother with Runnable?) Don't trust clients to faithfully return the jsessionid cookie either, and don't ever pass unsanitized request content to system functions, just like you wouldn't pass it to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the use of Runnable makes a difference but it's kind of pointless. I can't see where you declared your writer. If that's an instance variable of the servlet (i.e. not in the post method) then that one is prone to session swapping when used by two sessions at the same time. Try declaring it within the post method.

Comment: Thanks my friend!! The problem was the place of the declaration!
I declare the PrintWriter as a global variable. Now every this is working great!

Answer (score 0):

You need not to implement Runnable. By default Servlets are thread safe, which means a new thread is created for each of the request. If you are using some static variables then make sure you use them in a thread safe way. I think your thread creation may be troubling the tomcat/container to send the response in an incorrect way. In short I believe you are doing more than is required, container is there for your rescue.

Answer (score 0):

Any web container manages multi-threading of servlets. You need not implement your own thread. Remove the multi-threading from your code and it will work perfectly.

Comment: I wrote it at the beginning without the Runnable and when 2 devices send files at once one of the devices always receives an empty message. But i'll give it another chance.

Comment: Also as mentioned by howiewylie move the writer declaration inside doPost method.